# Apache CXF and WS-A properties

Tags: cxf, ws-addressing

Can anyone please tell me how to resolve this warning message I am receiving?

> WARN 13 Oct 2011 15:23:46,024 ContextUtils - WS-Addressing - failed to retrieve Message Addressing Properties from context

It doesn't seem to have any negative side effects although it clutters the logs and I don't like my software to complain.

Comment: Does your service require or use the WS-Addressing soap headers?  If not, can you configure your logger to not display messages from org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.ContextUtils?

Answer (score 0):

This link has information on how to adjust CXF logging levels:

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/debugging-and-logging.html

The code looks like it is logging this message at the 'fine' and 'warn' levels:

```
     if (maps != null) {
        LOG.log(Level.FINE, "current MAPs {0}", maps);
    } else if (!isProviderContext) {
        LogUtils.log(LOG, warnIfMissing ? Level.WARNING : Level.FINE, 
            "MAPS_RETRIEVAL_FAILURE_MSG");         
    }
```

You can adjust your logger accordingly.

Thanks.